# C# sharepoint List Item Collection

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, threshold

Ques. I have this method wit return type as 'List Item Collection'and my list in SharePoint contains more than 5000 items. In order to overcome the threshold, I need to fetch items in batches by putting row limit but I do not know what to put in the place of ?? so that the return type is also 'ListItemCollection'(SharePoint Client Context). Please help

```
private static ListItemCollection GetItemsFromSharePointSiteList(string strListName, string strCamlQuery, ClientContext clientContext)
{
    try
    {               
        ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;

        List listIPPMilestonesLE = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strListName);
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = strCamlQuery;
        query.DatesInUtc = false;

        //  ListItemCollection itemColl = new ListItemCollection();

        do
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = listIPPMilestonesLE.GetItems(query);
            clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
            {
                 ??
            }

            itemPosition = listItemCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition;

        } while (itemPosition != null);

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ErrorLog.Error(exc);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like below, Hope it will be a workaround and will help you

```
private static List<ListItem> GetItemsFromSharePointSiteList(string strListName, string strCamlQuery, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        try
        {
            ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;

            List listIPPMilestonesLE = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strListName);
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = strCamlQuery;
            query.DatesInUtc = false;

            var itemColl = new List<ListItem>();

            do
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = listIPPMilestonesLE.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                //
                itemColl.AddRange(listItemCollection);

                itemPosition = listItemCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition;

            } while (itemPosition != null);

            return itemColl;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ErrorLog.Error(exc);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set rowlimit in caml query.

For example:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                 "<Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>";
```

Then, Paging with ListItemCollectionPosition property.

Check this [sample](https://anvlpopescu.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/getting-list-items-with-c-csom-in-chunks/).